# How to create Fast Scrolling with front charecter to dispaly on screen when user Drag on List of Alphabet

Tags: android, android-contacts, fastscroll

I am New to android,

I have did the contact list like the Image look like the below,

[image]

but the problem is when i click on alphabet list the charterer is not displaying, it is only displaying only when I scroll through "FastScroller" but I don't want to display "FastScroll" on my screen : here is the link which show what I want,

[image]

this type of contact list is present with "samsung Galexy Y"

Please help me, Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

you should have a look at `android:fastScrollThumbDrawable` and `android:fastScrollTrackDrawable`  (both available only for API 11+). In the worst case scenario, you can use a transparent image to hide the fastscroller